# Is there a way to get a list of all uppercase and lowercase letters along with digits in python?

Tags: python

I know that there is a way to get a list of all ascii characters by using "string.printable" but would like to know if it is possible to only get a list of all the letters(both uppercase and lowercase) and all of the digits. In other words, how can I join "string.ascii_lowercase", "string.ascii_uppercase" and "string.digits" into a single list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_uppercase, string.digits` are all strings, you can concatenate with the `+` to form the string you wish. Or you can filter the longer `string.printable` to be what you want.

Concatenation:

```
>>> string.ascii_lowercase+string.ascii_uppercase+string.digits
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
```

You can also filter the longer string into the string that you want if the set a characters is more complicated than simple concatenation might accomplish or order of the longer string is important in the result.

To filter in Python, you can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> group=set(string.ascii_lowercase+string.ascii_uppercase+string.digits)
>>> [e for e in string.printable if e in group]
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

Then use `.join` to join the list together into a string:

```
>>> ''.join([e for e in string.printable if e in group])
'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

Or, use [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) which produces a string if given a string:

```
>>> filter(lambda c: c in group, string.printable)
'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

Or, as a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> ''.join(re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]', string.printable))
'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

Answer (score 4):

> how can I join "string.ascii_lowercase", "string.ascii_uppercase" and "string.digits" into a single list?

```
all_ascii_digits = string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase
```

Looking at some of the other answers please keep in mind the wisdom found in the Python language itself:

```
import this
wisdom = [s for s in this.s.split('\n') 
         if 'cersrenoyl' in s][0].decode('rot13')
print(wisdom)
```

Comment: Thanks. I just figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
string.printable[:62]
```

- Numbers [0:9]
- Lowercase [10:36]
- Uppercase [36:62]